# QML `TapHandler`: Find out which Button was pressed in `onSingleTapped`

Tags: qt, event-handling, qml

I have a simple task. I want to find out whether the left or right mouse button was pressed inside `TapHandler.onSingleTapped`:

```
TapHandler {
    acceptedButtons: Qt.LeftButton | Qt.RightButton

    onSingleTapped: function(eventPoint) {
        // Print if it was left or right button
    }
}
```

The supplied eventPoint does not contain this information. Where can I get this info?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go, taken from [TapHandler tapped() documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-taphandler.html#tapped-signal):

```
TapHandler {
    acceptedButtons: Qt.LeftButton | Qt.RightButton

    onSingleTapped: function(eventPoint) {
        console.log("tapped", eventPoint.event.device.name,
                    "button", eventPoint.event.button,
                    "@", eventPoint.scenePosition)
    }
}
```

But you could also use a dedicated `TapHandler` for each button type: [QtWS17 - Pointer Handlers for fluid applications in Qt Quick](https://youtu.be/W8SBSCf8eE0?t=1604)

Comment: Works like a charm, thank you. I knew about the approach using multiple TapHandlers (that was my current workaround), but I think this is the nicer solution. Cheers

Comment: I also think that the `event` property of the EventPoint is missing in the documentation

Comment: @skaldesh Yes the documentation is missing the property and I created a bugreport already. I also got told that the `EventPoint` interface will change in Qt 6, so keep that in mind when porting ;)

Comment: Great, thanks for reporting. Ill keep it in mind :)